# How do I compile my C program within Vim, but not to the current directory?

Tags: vim, c

So the command I've been using in Vim for a while is:

```
map <F10> :w<CR> :!clear; make %<<CR> :!./%<<CR>
```

Which takes the current name of the file, compiles and then runs it. However this pollutes my directory and when I want to upload them to github it makes it so that I have to delete all the files without extensions before I upload.

What I want to do is compile them all to a *bin* directory, so I tried to modify my command to the following:

```
map <F10> :w<CR> :!clear; make -C bin %<<CR> :!./bin/%<<CR>
```

I saw that the `-C` command changes the directory but this doesn't work as I get the error:

```
*** no rule to make target '17'. Stop.
```

What can I do to make this command work correctly?

```
map <F10> :w<CR> :!clear; make -C bin %<<CR> :!./bin/%<<CR>
```

Comment: Why not just put the things-that-are-not-for-github into a `.gitignore` file?

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing Vim's command `:make` with the OS executable `make(1)`.  When you type `make` at Vim's command line you're running Vim's `:make` command.  One of the effects of this is to run the OS command defined by Vim's option `makeprg`.

Now, `makeprg` happens to have the value `make` by default, so the OS command `make(1)` also gets run.  But Vim's command `:make` doesn't take options, so passing `-C bin` on Vim's command line doesn't translate to `make -C bin` being run.  If you want to change the OS command that gets run you need to do something like this:

```
let &makeprg = 'make -C /path/to/bin'
```

Then running `:make` in Vim will run the OS command `make -C /path/to/bin`.

However, as pointed out in comments, the better way to deal with this is to avoid the problem in the first place, and add all irrelevant files to `.gitignore`.  Otherwise sooner or later you'll still commit object files and what not to your Git repository.

Comment: Thanks, the reason I don't want to use a git ignore is that I'm going through a book and doing lots of exercises, so I'd have to do something like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19023550/how-do-i-add-files-without-dots-in-them-all-extension-less-files-to-the-gitign which seems messy to me. Seems more sensible to compile all files to a specfic directory and then ignore that.

Comment: Which is why writing a useful `.gitignore` is not completely trivial, either.